# How to install Ubuntu 16.04 from winrar file

Tags: system-installation

I have downloaded an Ubuntu winrar file. How do I install it?

Comment: Is the file a .iso file? Do you want to replace Windows, or install Ubuntu alongside it as a dual-boot setup?

Comment: if i replace it with all my data will be lost?!

Comment: Yes, replacing Windows will result in losing Windows and **all** the data on your computer. If you decide to go ahead with Ubuntu, make a backup of all your important files on a separate drive before you proceed. Also make sure you have some sort of Windows recovery media in case Ubuntu doesn't work out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the file you found a .iso file? If it is, that's good! But don't open it with WinRAR. Instead, burn it to a DVD using software that can burn a disc image, or use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to make a bootable USB stick.

Please be aware that there are different ways of installing Ubuntu, and some of them will erase **everything** on your computer, including Windows itself. Please make backups of all important files and read up on dual-boot setups, if that's what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you found as a winrar file.  The forms of Ubuntu 16.04 can be found at: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/, or http://www.ubuntu.com/download.  I wouldn't trust something that you are finding somewhere else.

There are some net install options as you can see from the official download site.  The best way would be to download the iso and burn it to a DVD, then follow the GUI for the install.

Comment: WinRAR supports opening ISO files as an archive format, so Hemanth's Windows machine has the .iso filetype set to open in WinRAR by default. If it is indeed an .iso file, Hemanth just needs to use Rufus to create a live USB

Comment: @NickWeinberg That is correct.  As my message said, I don't know where the file came from, but the key is having an ISO file and being sure to get it from a trusted source.  The many ways of install (including USB) are referenced on the links I provided.  I gave two links... one of them is directly to the version he specified.  The other is to alternate methods of install, as as I mentioned which includes net install.

Comment: i have downloaded it from direct link but my windows set it to winrar file type an now its not working...if i save it as an .iso il will it work? i needed it alongside the windows os. if i install it by erasing widows os all my other drive data will be lost?

Comment: Do as I mentioned in the answer and burn the ISO to a DVD.  Then boot to the DVD.  Once you boot, one of the options will be to install Ubuntu alongside Windows.